# How to incorporate individual cells into existing cell blocks?

Tags: prison-architect

I'm having a problem with my new cell block. I created it the same as the last one but I can't seem to manage to incorporate the individual cells with the existing cell block. This is making it really annoying to search the cells, because I have to do every one individually instead of just "Search Cell Block". Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi @MrMANI and welcome to StackExchange! Can you post a screenshot of your two cellblocks? That would help us solve the problem.

Comment: A similar question: [How do I create a cell block so I can search the whole block at once?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150707/how-do-i-create-a-cell-block-so-i-can-search-the-whole-block-at-once/150927#150927)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no where to incorporate them without knocking them down.