# How do I create a cell block so I can search the whole block at once?

Tags: prison-architect

When building individual cell blocks, even if they're inside a single wall rectangle (fence around all cells and personnel can be assigned to guard it) it doesn't automatically count as one cell block. So when searching cells, I have to click on each cell and press search. I'd like the "search cell block" option to be useful, and yet it only searches a single cell.

How do I create a cell block from individual cells?

Comment: There is a similar question about adding new cells into existing cell blocks, but I'm asking about creating cell blocks from all brand new cells.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your prison? It would help to see how you have laid out the walls.

Comment: The cells are surrounded by a fence with just 1 door. Guards can be assigned to guard inside the fence, so I guess that qualifies as a separate area.

Comment: Short answer: I don't think you can. Longer answer: I think cells need to be physically next to each other (inside the same building - not necessarily sharing adjoining walls, but that's a good way of designing them) to count as a cellblock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grouping cells using a fence will not create a *cell block*. Each [cell](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Cell) (room) needs to be part of the same building (foundation):

[image: Foundation]

See this example of how to lay out a cell block:

[image: Cell Block]

It is one large building with walls dividing up the space. Once you have cells in a building they will be searched when you select "search cell block".

More than one "cell block" can exist within the same building (foundation) if the corridors are separated with doors. (Thanks for pointing that out Rory)

Comment: This isn't the full story, however, as if you have two areas of cells accessible by a a corridor with jail doors at the end of the corridor then areas of cells can be counted as different cell blocks despite sharing a foundation.

Comment: @Rory - You are correct. I was just trying to give a simple description that would help the OP, tricky when they did not include a picture of their cell block.

Comment: My problem was I just built walls without any foundation.